# Can I filter the attributes a users sees in GoodData?

Tags: gooddata

I'm a good data admin and I was wondering if I could create a simplified view of our project to present to a set of users. We have a lot of facts/attributes in our project which we use for financial reporting etc. which are not relevant to these users and I want to hide them to make it easy for them to explore a simple set of data.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can easily hide attributes and facts from your project, but there are some options how you can help your users.

They don't need to use facts - you can build metrics on top of them and then hide those metric which are non-essential, delete dimensions you thought you would use but you didn't, etc...

Anyway - at some point I would consider to build second project with identical, but simplified writer and let them use simplier project...